# How to format my array

Tags: php

I have an $array :

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
 array(3887) {
   [38]=>
   string(5) "Cassa"
   [39]=>
   string(11) "Abano Terme"
   [41]=>
   string(13) "Abbiategrasso"
   [42]=>
   string(9) "Acitrezza"
```

and i want it to look like this :

```
"{'38':'CAssa', '39':'Abano Terme', '41':'Abbiategrasso'}"
```

so i can use it with [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Thanks.

Comment: use `json_encode($arr)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using the php function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)

```
$array = ['38' => 'cassa', '42' => 'home'];
$json = json_encode($array);
var_dump($json); // should output "{"38":"cassa","42":"home"}"
```